# WooCommerce remove product from loop by id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide woocommerce products from the loop if any of the variation are out of stock.

What I have tried so far

1: Get the current logged in users "region"
2: Get a list of all product variation which are regions to check against the user region.
3: Run a check and if matches hide the product
4: Exclude the product from the loop

Any incite would be greatly appreciated.

```
function tm_remove_product_stock_region($query) {

    $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();

/** Get users region. */
    $user_region = tm_get_user_region();

    $post__in = array();

    foreach ( $product_variations as $variation ) {

        /** Get products regions. */
        $product_region = $variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_regions'];

        if ($user_region === $product_region && !$variation->is_in_stock()) {


          $post__in[] = $variation['product_id'];

          add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible', function($is_visible, $id) {
                $is_visible = false;
                return $is_visible;
            }, 10,2);


        } else if ($user_region === $product_region && $variation->is_in_stock()) {

          $post__in[] = $variation['product_id'];


            add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible', function($is_visible, $id) {
                $is_visible = true;
                return $is_visible;
            }, 10,2);


        }

    }

    if(is_array($post__in) && $post__in != null){
        $query->set('post__in', $post__in);
    }

    return $query;

 }

 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region', 10, 2);
```

**Update 2:**

I update the above and got it to work, BUT woocommerce_product_is_visible filter only works on category archive pages, Noting gets filtered for search page or when WP_Query is used on a custom page which is a real shame. Also is their a reason why $is_visible for woocommerce wont work with pre_get_posts

```
Function tm_remove_product_stock_region($is_visible, $id) {

    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

    $product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());
    $product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();

    /** Get users region. */
    $user_region = tm_get_user_region();

    foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {

       /** Get products regions. */
        $product_region = $variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_regions'];

       if (!$product->is_in_stock() && $user_region === $product_region) {

            $is_visible = false;
            return $is_visible;

       }    

       else if ($product->is_in_stock() && $user_region === $product_region) {

            $is_visible = true;
            return $is_visible;

       }
    }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region', 10,2);
```

**Update 3:**

After more hours of fiddling about I just noticed that `$product_variable` in both functions returns a different set of results ie with "woocommerce_product_is_visible" the products parent ID get returned but with "pre_get_posts" it's the variation ID.

So I don't get the result I wanted and pre_get_posts fails which is what  I actually need to work, I still have not solved this.

Comment: Are you actually wanting the following: ` I'm trying to hide woocommerce products from the loop if ALL of the variations are out of stock.`

Comment: My main issue is the store is not like a normal store where you set the parent product to have a certain amount of stock, in the store im developing its the children of that product ie. the variations who have the stock set if that makes sense, dust the reason for the if statements.

Comment: The code you commented out seems to be more useful than the current code.

Comment: Is there anyway my updated code to work on custom pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I managed to get it working right see below for answer if anyone has a similar need.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','remove_products');

function remove_products($query) {
   if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

      $user_region = tm_get_user_region();
      $current_category = get_queried_object();

      $args = array(
         'post_type'                => 'product',
         'post_status'              => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page'           => 36,
         'orderBy'                  => 'title',
         'tax_query'                => array(
            array(
               'taxonomy'           => 'product_cat',
               'field'              => 'term_id',
               'terms'              => $current_category->term_id,
            )
         )
      );

      $loop = get_posts($args);
      $post__in = array();

      foreach ($loop as $post) {

         //Product object
         $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

         //Get product info i.e variations > meta keys
         $product_variations = $product->get_children();

         foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {

            // Store only the meta keys needed
            $product_region = get_post_meta($variation, 'attribute_pa_regions'); // 'region name'
            $stock_status = get_post_meta($variation, '_stock_status'); // 'outofstock'

            // Regional and stock check
            if(in_array($user_region, $product_region) && in_array('outofstock', $stock_status)) { // === wont work here
               $post__in[] = $post->ID;
            }
         }

      }

      //Exclude the product
      if(is_array($post__in) && $post__in != null) {
         $query->set('post__not_in', $post__in);
      }

   }

}
```

**Please note** that `$product->get_available_variations()` will return a lot of information which will greatly slow down you page load, its best to use `get_post_meta(the_id, 'meta_key_name');` instead to get only the data required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the meta_query before loop,

```
function tm_remove_product_stock_region($query) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
        'key'       => '_stock_status',
        'value'     => 'outofstock',
        'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
    )));
return $query;

    }
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tm_remove_product_stock_region');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
$has_items_in_stock = false;
foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {

    /** Get products regions. */
    $product_region = $variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_regions'];

    if ( $user_region === $product_region && $variation['is_in_stock'] ) {
        $has_items_in_stock = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($has_items_in_stock ) {
    //show product
    //show variations
    //..
}
```